# The difference between "departure" and "deviation"

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a technical report that highlights the advantages of 2D (two dimensional) modeling compared with 1D modeling. I would like to mention that the 2D simulations better capture the physics of the studied phenomemon and show the **departure/deviation** of 1D results from the measurements.

I have seen numerous standard examples where both departure and deviation are used to describe how far something is from an expected result or an accepted norm, but I am not sure which one fits academic context I am interested in.

Comment: "Deviation" sounds slightly better to me where the amount of the deviation is precisely measurable. "Departure" sounds fine, too, but I would more likely reserve it for situations where measurement isn't as important ("departure from standard procedure").

Comment: You should show that you looked up the words in a dictionary, and tell us why that did not satisfy you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary comparison shows little significant difference in these terms. In your context the prose describes differences between the (simulated numerical) predictions of a 1-D model and measurements, and between a 2-D model and measurements. These differences are conventionally discussed in terms of the difference between the measurement and its modelled value (perhaps the mean, or some other statistical regressive prediction). The terms *departure* and *deviation* are both used.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deviation)
>
> deviation:
>
> a difference from what is usual or expected

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deviation)
>
> departure:
>
> a change from what is expected, or from what has happened before

For examples:

> [Indeed](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-calculate-average-deviation)
>
> deviation example:
>
> *In this article, we discuss what average deviation is, how to calculate it, as well as the differences between absolute and average deviation, mean average and average deviation from the mean and standard deviation versus average deviation.*

or

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/departure)
>
> departure example:
>
> *The spike in Arkansas' total coronavirus case count Friday was larger by 18 than the one the previous Friday, the second departure this week from a recent overall downward trend in new cases.*

*Deviation* has a special significance because it is conventionally used in the important statistical estimate "Standard deviation", which is a measure of the differences between a set of values and the expected values. This means that you will be on safe ground if you choose to use *deviation*.

Note: I guess you know about *standard deviation*, but for completeness this link is useful: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviation.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to mean inconsistency or abnormal behavior of the 1D results from the measurements, using **deviation** would be more academic. The word **departure** sounds more like leaving something. According to the Oxford dictionary

> deviation (from something) the act of moving away from what is normal or acceptable; a difference from what is expected or acceptable